# Swift: programatically copy auto layout constraints from one view to another

Tags: swift

I have a `UIButton` that I set up with auto layout constraints in a storyboard. i also have a `UIView` that I initiate in the `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method. I make this view have (almost) all the same properties as the `UIButton` but when it I run it in the simulator it doesn't "stick" to the button. here's what I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let someView = UIView()
        someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        someView.frame = someButton.bounds
        someView.frame.origin = someButton.frame.origin
        someView.autoresizingMask = someButton.autoresizingMask
        someView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        someView.layer.cornerRadius = someButton.layer.cornerRadius
        someView.clipsToBounds = true
        someView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        view.insertSubview(someView, belowSubview: someButton)
    }

}
```

I guess I’m missing the `someView`.auto layout constraint?

**EDIT: i thought accessing the `UIButton`'s constraints would work but they appear to be an empty array. are story board constraints are hidden?**

```
someView.addConstraints(someButton.constraints)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying the constraints that way fails because:

- the constraints in the storyboard are added to the superview and not the button itself
- the constraints you try to copy are referencing the button and not your new view

Instead of copying the constraints keep it simple and create new ones and reference the button:

```
    let someView = UIView()
    someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(someView)

    view.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: someButton, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: someButton, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: someButton, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: someButton, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    ])
```

Comment: can you access the buttons constraints from the superview? I quite like control dragging :-)

Comment: You can but why would you prefer to do it that way? Basically you need to loop through the constraints of the superview and compare firstItem and secondItem with the button. Not a particularly safe approach though.

Comment: you're right I guess - I just thought you could get more desired precision doing it by hand. Need to touch up my auto layout...